# Parse MM:SS from a string column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have a column that represents minutes and seconds as 20:00, or 19:58.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'clock': ['19:58', '20:00']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to truly express this as an object in a pandas column that is minutes and seconds.

I have attempted to use `pd.to_datetime(df.clock, format="%M:%S")`, and that doesn't error, but the a time of `20:00` (twenty minutes, zero seconds) parses as `1900-01-01 00:20:00`.

I am drawing a blank on how to retain just the minutes and seconds in the result so that I can look the time elapsed, in seconds, between records.

The trick?

I am looking at sporting data, and there are 3 periods in the game, each that count backwards from twenty minutes, so its not as if I can just append the game date and move on, as each time sequence can appear 3 times (or more).

Comment: I’m not very familiar with time in pandas, but you should take a look at [Time deltas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html), it might be what you’re looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) function which you could try.  But it seems to expect things in `hh:mm:ss` format, so I had to augment the input:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> times = ['20:00', '19:58', '00:05']
>>> pd.to_timedelta(['00:'+i for i in times]) # manually convert to hh:mm:ss

TimedeltaIndex(['0 days 00:20:00', '0 days 00:19:58', '0 days 00:00:05'], dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq=None)
```

What I mean is that `deltas = pd.to_timedelta(times)` fails with `ValueError: expected hh:mm:ss format` I don't see a `format` paramter, like `pd.to_datetime` unfortunately.

You can then access the `total_seconds` if you want to make some elapsed time calculations:

```
>>> deltas.total_seconds()

Float64Index([1200.0, 1198.0, 5.0], dtype='float64')
```

I think you could still use `pd.to_datetime`, but you would just have to add the step of subtracting the midnight timestamp on the date of each created timestamp, like so:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> times = ['20:00', '19:58', '00:05']
>>> times = pd.to_datetime(times, format="%M:%S")
>>> deltas = times - times.floor('D')
# deltas is the same as above
```